# Set of float numbers, append numbers to empty list in sets . Python

Tags: python, list, function, append, max

Set of numbers

```
n_set = [1.0,3.2,4.5,8.2,1.3,2.2,5.6,9.8,2.4,5.5,6.7]
```

So i'm trying to construct a function that takes a set of numbers and creates a list of lists from the number set. i'm trying to make each list have a subset of numbers from the original set that increases until it hits a maximum value

```
organized_set = [[1.0,3.2,4.5,8.2],[1.3,2.2,5.6,9.8],[2.4,5.5,6.7]]
```

i was thinking something along the lines of

```
for i,k in zip(range(0,len(n_set)),n_set):
    set = []
    d = dict(zip(i,k))
    d2 = dict(zip(k,i))
    if d[i] < d[d2[i]+1]:
        set.append(k)
```

this isn't making sense.  i'm working on a much more complicated function but this is one part of it that is throwing me off.  any help would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this iterative approach:

```
n_set = [1.0,3.2,4.5,8.2,1.3,2.2,5.6,9.8,2.4,5.5,6.7]

prev = None
result = []
current = []
for x in n_set:
    if prev is not None and x < prev:
        # Next element is smaller than previous element.
        # The current group is finished.
        result.append(current)

        # Start a new group.
        current = [x]
    else:
        # Add the element to the current group.
        current.append(x)

    # Remember the value of the current element.
    prev = x

# Append the last group to the result.
result.append(current)

print result
```

Result:

```
[[1.0, 3.2, 4.5, 8.2], [1.3, 2.2, 5.6, 9.8], [2.4, 5.5, 6.7]]
```

Comment: Awesome! it is working thank you so much.  i'm a little confused on how a couple of the parts work tho . . . 1] what does it mean when you are assigning prev = None because "if x < prev:" you append the current list ? There is nothing in the current list at that moment I thouhgt? 2] prev = x i don't really understand why the previous one would be = to x . . . sorry if the questions are a little weird i'm just trying to understand it completely

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: I updated my answer and added some comments to the code. I hope that helps. If you are still having trouble, try installing an IDE with debugging support and step through the code line by line to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2

     temp=[]
     res=[]

     for i in n:
          temp.append(i)
          if len(temp)>1 and i<temp[-2]:
                  res.append(temp[:-1])
                  temp=[i]
     res.append(temp)
     print(res)
```